# How to parse json file in Weka using JSONLoader in Java IDE?

Tags: java, json, weka, naivebayes

I want to use Weka in order to parse an existing json file in java eclipse. I believe this can be done using the JSONLoader class. I am working on Naive Bayes classifier.

This is the data that I want to parse.

```
 {"header":{  
    "relation":"relationtest",  
    "attributes":{  
    "name":"Nominal",  
    "company":"Nominal",  
    "city":"Nominal",  
    "country":"Nominal"  
    }  
    },  
    "data":[  
    ["Andrew","AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc.","Washington","UnitedStates"],  
    ["Kyle","AS16509 Amazon.in, Inc.","NewDelhi","India"]  
    ]  
    }
```

But, I end up getting a 'java.lang.NullPointerException' when I run the below code snippet

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(argv[0]);  
    JSONLoader loader = new JSONLoader();  
    loader.setSource(fis);  
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
```

Note: The json file is passed as an argument.

I believe there is some problem with the way the attributes are written. 
How can I solve this issue?